# The flume always stop automatically with agent-shutdown-hook in monitor logs

Tags: hdfs, apache-kafka, flume

I have a Flume running in the Linux Ubuntu, it is running better, but it always stop during running after about ONE day, following is the flume configuration:

```
    nginx.channels=ch-spooling ch-tail
    nginx.sources=spooling-source tail-source
    nginx.sinks=hdfs-spooling kafka-tail

    nginx.channels.ch-spooling.type=file
    nginx.channels.ch-spooling.checkpointDir=/home/hadoop/flume/file-channel/ch-spooling/checkpoint
    nginx.channels.ch-spooling.dataDirs=/home/hadoop/flume/file-channel/ch-spooling/data
    nginx.channels.ch-spooling.capacity=1000
    nginx.channels.ch-spooling.transactionCapacity=100
    nginx.channels.ch-spooling.capacity=100000

    nginx.channels.ch-tail.type=file
    nginx.channels.ch-tail.checkpointDir=/home/hadoop/flume/file-channel/ch-tail/checkpoint
    nginx.channels.ch-tail.dataDirs=/home/hadoop/flume/file-channel/ch-tail/data
    nginx.channels.ch-tail.capacity=1000
    nginx.channels.ch-tail.transactionCapacity=100
    nginx.channels.ch-tail.capacity=100000

    nginx.sources.spooling-source.type=spooldir
    nginx.sources.spooling-source.channels=ch-spooling
    nginx.sources.spooling-source.spoolDir=/usr/local/nginx/logs/flume_logs
    nginx.sources.spooling-source.fileHeader=true
    nginx.sources.spooling-source.fileHeaderKey=file
    nginx.sources.spooling-source.basenameHeader=true
    nginx.sources.spooling-source.basenameHeaderKey=basename
    nginx.sources.spooling-source.deletePolicy=never

    nginx.sources.spooling-source.consumeOrder=oldest
    nginx.sources.spooling-source.recursiveDirectorySearch=false
    nginx.sources.spooling-source.batchSize=100
    nginx.sources.spooling-source.inputCharset=UTF-8

    nginx.sources.spooling-source.decodeErrorPolicy=IGNORE
    nginx.sources.spooling-source.selector.type=replicating
    nginx.sources.spooling-source.interceptors=i1 i2
    nginx.sources.spooling-source.interceptors.i1.type=timestamp
    nginx.sources.spooling-source.interceptors.i2.type=host
    nginx.sources.spooling-source.interceptors.i2.useIP=true
    nginx.sources.spooling-source.interceptors.i2.hostHeader=host

    nginx.sources.tail-source.type=TAILDIR
    nginx.sources.tail-source.channels=ch-tail
    nginx.sources.tail-source.filegroups=hnrapi hnrapierror
    nginx.sources.tail-source.filegroups.hnrapi=/usr/local/nginx/logs/hnr-api.access.log
    nginx.sources.tail-source.filegroups.hnrapierror=/usr/local/nginx/logs/error.log
    nginx.sources.tail-source.positionFile=/home/hadoop/flume/file-channel/ch-tail/taildir_position.json
    nginx.sources.tail-source.headers.hnrapi.topic=hnrapi
    nginx.sources.tail-source.headers.hnrapierror.topic=hnrapierror
    nginx.sources.tail-source.skipToEnd=true
    nginx.sources.tail-source.interceptors=i1 i2
    nginx.sources.tail-source.interceptors.i1.type=timestamp
    nginx.sources.tail-source.interceptors.i2.type=host
    nginx.sources.tail-source.interceptors.i2.useIP=true
    nginx.sources.tail-source.interceptors.i2.hostHeader=host

    nginx.sinks.hdfs-spooling.channel=ch-spooling
    nginx.sinks.hdfs-spooling.type=hdfs
    nginx.sinks.hdfs-spooling.hdfs.fileType=DataStream
    nginx.sinks.hdfs-spooling.hdfs.writeFormat=Text

    nginx.sinks.hdfs-spooling.hdfs.path=hdfs://namenode1:9000/flume/nginx/%Y-%m-%d

    nginx.sinks.hdfs-spooling.hdfs.filePrefix=%{basename}.[%{host}]
    nginx.sinks.hdfs-spooling.hdfs.fileSuffix=
    nginx.sinks.hdfs-spooling.hdfs.inUseSuffix=.tmp
    nginx.sinks.hdfs-spooling.hdfs.rollInterval=0
    nginx.sinks.hdfs-spooling.hdfs.rollSize=1073741824
    nginx.sinks.hdfs-spooling.hdfs.rollCount=0
    nginx.sinks.hdfs-spooling.hdfs.idleTimeout=60

    nginx.sinks.kafka-tail.channel=ch-tail
    nginx.sinks.kafka-tail.type=org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink
    nginx.sinks.kafka-tail.kafka.bootstrap.servers=192.47.180.63:9192,192.27.125.123:9192,192.27.124.96:9192
    nginx.sinks.kafka-tail.flumeBatchSize=32
    nginx.sinks.kafka-tail.kafka.producer.acks=1
    nginx.sinks.kafka-tail.useFlumeEventFormat=false
```

I collect nginx logs with taildir and spooldir, taildir have target to kafka, spooldir have target to hdfs.

The following is the flume monitor logs just partly:

> 2017-03-06 18:17:54,302 (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.SinkCallback.onCompletion(KafkaSink.java:456)] Elapsed time for send: 13
>   2017-03-06 18:18:14,230 (Log-BackgroundWorker-ch-spooling) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.channel.file.FlumeEventQueue.checkpoint(FlumeEventQueue.java:138)] Checkpoint not required
>   2017-03-06 18:18:14,408 (Log-BackgroundWorker-ch-tail) [INFO - org.apache.flume.channel.file.EventQueueBackingStoreFile.beginCheckpoint(EventQueueBackingStoreFile.java:227)] Start checkpoint for /home/hadoop/flume/file-channel/ch-tail/checkpoint/checkpoint, elements to sync = 8
>   2017-03-06 18:18:14,415 (Log-BackgroundWorker-ch-tail) [INFO - org.apache.flume.channel.file.EventQueueBackingStoreFile.checkpoint(EventQueueBackingStoreFile.java:252)] Updating checkpoint metadata: logWriteOrderID: 1488782535982, queueSize: 0, queueHead: 1642
>   2017-03-06 18:18:14,420 (Log-BackgroundWorker-ch-tail) [INFO - org.apache.flume.channel.file.Log.writeCheckpoint(Log.java:1052)] Updated checkpoint for file: /home/hadoop/flume/file-channel/ch-tail/data/log-16 position: 391719 logWriteOrderID: 1488782535982
>   2017-03-06 18:18:14,420 (Log-BackgroundWorker-ch-tail) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.channel.file.Log.removeOldLogs(Log.java:1115)] Files currently in use: [16]
>   2017-03-06 18:18:14,484 (conf-file-poller-0) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:127)] Checking file:/home/hadoop/flume/conf/flume-conf.properties for changes
>   2017-03-06 18:18:44,230 (Log-BackgroundWorker-ch-spooling) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.channel.file.FlumeEventQueue.checkpoint(FlumeEventQueue.java:138)] Checkpoint not required
>   2017-03-06 18:18:44,420 (Log-BackgroundWorker-ch-tail) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.channel.file.FlumeEventQueue.checkpoint(FlumeEventQueue.java:138)] Checkpoint not required
>   2017-03-06 18:18:44,484 (conf-file-poller-0) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:127)] Checking file:/home/hadoop/flume/conf/flume-conf.properties for changes
>   2017-03-06 18:19:14,230 (Log-BackgroundWorker-ch-spooling) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.channel.file.FlumeEventQueue.checkpoint(FlumeEventQueue.java:138)] Checkpoint not required
>   2017-03-06 18:19:14,421 (Log-BackgroundWorker-ch-tail) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.channel.file.FlumeEventQueue.checkpoint(FlumeEventQueue.java:138)] Checkpoint not required
>   2017-03-06 18:19:14,485 (conf-file-poller-0) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:127)] Checking file:/home/hadoop/flume/conf/flume-conf.properties for changes
>   2017-03-06 18:19:44,231 (Log-BackgroundWorker-ch-spooling) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.channel.file.FlumeEventQueue.checkpoint(FlumeEventQueue.java:138)] Checkpoint not required
>   2017-03-06 18:19:44,421 (Log-BackgroundWorker-ch-tail) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.channel.file.FlumeEventQueue.checkpoint(FlumeEventQueue.java:138)] Checkpoint not required
>   2017-03-06 18:19:44,485 (conf-file-poller-0) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:127)] Checking file:/home/hadoop/flume/conf/flume-conf.properties for changes
>   2017-03-06 18:19:54,577 (PollableSourceRunner-TaildirSource-tail-source) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.taildir.TaildirSource.closeTailFiles(TaildirSource.java:288)] Closed file: /usr/local/nginx/logs/hnr-api.access.log, inode: 2237741, pos: 3183
>   2017-03-06 18:19:59,307 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink.process(KafkaSink.java:187)] event #0
>   2017-03-06 18:19:59,310 (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.SinkCallback.onCompletion(KafkaSink.java:455)] Acked message partition:1 ofset:122
>   2017-03-06 18:19:59,310 (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.SinkCallback.onCompletion(KafkaSink.java:456)] Elapsed time for send: 3
>   2017-03-06 18:20:14,231 (Log-BackgroundWorker-ch-spooling) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.channel.file.FlumeEventQueue.checkpoint(FlumeEventQueue.java:138)] Checkpoint not required
>   2017-03-06 18:20:14,421 (Log-BackgroundWorker-ch-tail) [INFO - org.apache.flume.channel.file.EventQueueBackingStoreFile.beginCheckpoint(EventQueueBackingStoreFile.java:227)] Start checkpoint for /home/hadoop/flume/file-channel/ch-tail/checkpoint/checkpoint, elements to sync = 1
>   2017-03-06 18:20:14,427 (Log-BackgroundWorker-ch-tail) [INFO - org.apache.flume.channel.file.EventQueueBackingStoreFile.checkpoint(EventQueueBackingStoreFile.java:252)] Updating checkpoint metadata: logWriteOrderID: 1488782535987, queueSize: 0, queueHead: 1642
>   2017-03-06 18:20:14,432 (Log-BackgroundWorker-ch-tail) [INFO - org.apache.flume.channel.file.Log.writeCheckpoint(Log.java:1052)] Updated checkpoint for file: /home/hadoop/flume/file-channel/ch-tail/data/log-16 position: 392302 logWriteOrderID: 1488782535987
>   2017-03-06 18:20:14,432 (Log-BackgroundWorker-ch-tail) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.channel.file.Log.removeOldLogs(Log.java:1115)] Files currently in use: [16]
>   2017-03-06 18:20:14,485 (conf-file-poller-0) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:127)] Checking file:/home/hadoop/flume/conf/flume-conf.properties for changes
>   2017-03-06 18:20:44,231 (Log-BackgroundWorker-ch-spooling) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.channel.file.FlumeEventQueue.checkpoint(FlumeEventQueue.java:138)] Checkpoint not required
>   2017-03-06 18:20:44,433 (Log-BackgroundWorker-ch-tail) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.channel.file.FlumeEventQueue.checkpoint(FlumeEventQueue.java:138)] Checkpoint not required
>   2017-03-06 18:20:44,485 (conf-file-poller-0) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:127)] Checking file:/home/hadoop/flume/conf/flume-conf.properties for changes
>   2017-03-06 18:20:46,224 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor.stop(LifecycleSupervisor.java:78)] Stopping lifecycle supervisor 13
>   2017-03-06 18:20:46,227 (**agent-shutdown-hook**) [INFO - org.apache.flume.channel.file.FileChannel.stop(FileChannel.java:324)] Stopping FileChannel ch-tail { dataDirs: [/home/hadoop/flume/file-channel/ch-tail/data] }...
>   2017-03-06 18:20:46,227 (**agent-shutdown-hook**) [INFO - org.apache.flume.channel.file.EventQueueBackingStoreFile.beginCheckpoint(EventQueueBackingStoreFile.java:227)] Start checkpoint for /home/hadoop/flume/file-channel/ch-tail/checkpoint/checkpoint, elements to sync = 0
>   2017-03-06 18:20:46,233 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.channel.file.EventQueueBackingStoreFile.checkpoint(EventQueueBackingStoreFile.java:252)] Updating checkpoint metadata: logWriteOrderID: 1488782535988, queueSize: 0, queueHead: 1642
>   2017-03-06 18:20:46,238 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.channel.file.Log.writeCheckpoint(Log.java:1052)] Updated checkpoint for file: /home/hadoop/flume/file-channel/ch-tail/data/log-16 position: 392302 logWriteOrderID: 1488782535988
>   **Attempting to shutdown background worker**.
>   2017-03-06 18:20:46,238 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.channel.file.Log.shutdownWorker(Log.java:868)] Attempting to shutdown background worker.
>   2017-03-06 18:20:46,238 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.channel.file.LogFile$Writer.close(LogFile.java:384)] Closing /home/hadoop/flume/file-channel/ch-tail/data/log-16
>   2017-03-06 18:20:46,238 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.channel.file.LogFile$RandomReader.close(LogFile.java:520)] Closing RandomReader /home/hadoop/flume/file-channel/ch-tail/data/log-16
>   2017-03-06 18:20:46,243 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.channel.file.LogFile$RandomReader.close(LogFile.java:520)] Closing RandomReader /home/hadoop/flume/file-channel/ch-tail/data/log-15
>   2017-03-06 18:20:46,249 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:149)] Component type: CHANNEL, name: ch-tail stopped
>   2017-03-06 18:20:46,249 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:155)] Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: ch-tail. channel.start.time == 1488782534266
>   2017-03-06 18:20:46,249 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:161)] Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: ch-tail. channel.stop.time == 1488795646249
>   2017-03-06 18:20:46,249 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:177)] Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: ch-tail. channel.capacity == 100000
>   2017-03-06 18:20:46,249 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:177)] Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: ch-tail. channel.current.size == 0
>   2017-03-06 18:20:46,249 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:177)] Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: ch-tail. channel.event.put.attempt == 834
>   2017-03-06 18:20:46,249 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:177)] Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: ch-tail. channel.event.put.success == 834
>   2017-03-06 18:20:46,249 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:177)] Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: ch-tail. channel.event.take.attempt == 3559
>   2017-03-06 18:20:46,249 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:177)] Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: ch-tail. channel.event.take.success == 834
>   2017-03-06 18:20:46,249 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.stop(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:84)] Configuration provider stopping
>   2017-03-06 18:20:46,249 (agent-shutdown-hook) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.stop(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:96)] Configuration provider stopped
>   2017-03-06 18:20:46,249 (agent-shutdown-hook) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.SinkRunner.stop(SinkRunner.java:104)] Waiting for runner thread to exit
>   2017-03-06 18:20:46,249 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:155)] Interrupted while processing an event. Exiting.
>   2017-03-06 18:20:46,249 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:171)] Polling runner exiting. Metrics:{ name:null counters:{runner.interruptions=1, runner.backoffs.consecutive=12, runner.backoffs=2689} }
>   2017-03-06 18:20:46,250 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.close(KafkaProducer.java:613)] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms.
>   2017-03-06 18:20:46,250 (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [DEBUG - org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:134)] Beginning shutdown of Kafka producer I/O thread, sending remaining records.
>   2017-03-06 18:20:46,250 (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [DEBUG - org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics.removeSensor(Metrics.java:220)] Removed sensor with name connections-closed:client-id-producer-1

Please anybody can help me!! Thanks.

Comment: Anybody can help me!!

Comment: I have resolved this issue, which maybe caused by multiple file with the same name in flume SpoolDir folder, I have the duplicate crontab command which result in this suitation. Flume got normal after I remove the other duplicate crontab command.